# LoadLibrary fails under Vista x64

Tags: c#, winapi, loadlibrary

Right after I moved from XP to Vista,I realized my C# programs don't work.

This is the situation: I wrote a C++ dll that I use in my C# application.The DLL worked fine in XP,but when I moved to Vista it's not longer working in C#.

I tested it in Delphi,works fine,but C# - no.

I wrote additional code to make my check easier in C#.

```
        if (LoadLibrary("blowfish.dll") == 0)
        {
            Misc.LogToFile("error", true);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

It doesn't need C++ runtime,because Its compiled with the libraries and it works in Delphi on Vista,but not C#.

Where could the problem be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vista x64.The dll is compiled for x32.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On x64 platform the JIT will compile your program into x64, since your native C++ is compiled to x86 it will fail to load it.
You need to explicitly tell the JIT to compile your program to x86, you can do it using [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx) or the project settings set the CPU type to x86 (Under Build/Platform target)

Answer (score 2):

Shay has the quick fix - make your whole application 32 bit so it runs under WOW64.

However, the "better" solution is to rebuild your C++ dll as 64-bit code so that your entire program can run natively on the 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile normally, the CLR will run your app as 64-bit on x64 Windows and 32-bit on x86 Windows. You have to load the correct native image for the platform. One solution is to do as Shay suggested and force your app to run in a 32-bit CLR.

You can also make your application look at the native pointer size and load the correct native image.

```
string blowfishdll = "blowfish.dll";
// detect 64-bit installations by looking at the native pointer size
if( 64 == IntPtr.Size * 8  )
    blowfishdll = "blowfish-x64.dll"

if (LoadLibrary( blowfishdll ) == 0)        
{
    Misc.LogToFile("error", true);            
    Application.Exit();        
}
```